# Changing the Number of Labels

Tags: labels, alignat

Here, lets say I have

```
\begin{alignat}{4}
            &x_1+x_2+&x_3&\leq 3,\\
            &2x_1 + &3x_3&\leq 5.
\end{alignat}
```

Since I already have an `alignat` earlier in the document, with three lines, it will label these (4) and (5). But since this is for a new question, (I'm typing an assignment), I want these to label as (1) and (2) instead. How do I manually change the labels?

Comment: Are your assignments numbered (with a counter)?

Comment: you can use `\setcounter{equation}{1001}` to get whetever number you want but better would be to tell latex that equations should be numbered within questions then it would reset automatically but as you have shown no code can not suggest the markup for that.